# Sending extra parameters to handler

Tags: node.js

Basically I have this

```
CSGOCli.playerProfileRequest(CSGOCli.ToAccountID(userId));
```

But I want some extra information I want in the event listener. So I thought I could change it to this:

```
CSGOCli.playerProfileRequest(CSGOCli.ToAccountID(row.steam64ID), "checkRank", myData[0]);
```

This is the event listener right now:

```
CSGOCli.on("playerProfile", function(profile) {
```

So I'm guessing it would have to look like this:

```
CSGOCli.on("playerProfile", function(profile, eventType, userData) {
```

Now the handler that handles these functions is this:

```
CSGO.CSGOClient.prototype.playerProfileRequest = function(accountId, even_type, my_data req_level, callback) {
callback = callback || null;
if (!this._gcReady) {
    if (this.debug) {
        util.log("GC not ready");
    }
    return null;
}

if (this.debug) {
    util.log("Sending player profile request");
}

var payload = new protos.CMsgGCCStrike15_v2_ClientRequestPlayersProfile({
    account_id: accountId, 
    request_level: req_level || 32
});

this._gc.send({msg:CSGO.ECSGOCMsg.k_EMsgGCCStrike15_v2_ClientRequestPlayersProfile, proto: {}}, payload.toBuffer(), callback);

};

var handlers = CSGO.CSGOClient.prototype._handlers;

handlers[CSGO.ECSGOCMsg.k_EMsgGCCStrike15_v2_PlayersProfile] = function onPlayerProfileResponse(message) {
    var playerProfileResponse = protos.CMsgGCCStrike15_v2_PlayersProfile.decode(message);

    if (this.debug) {
        util.log("Received player profile");
    }
    this.emit("playerProfile", playerProfileResponse, eventType, userData);
};
```

Like you can see, in the last line "this.emit" I already changed how I want it to look but now this is the place where my problem comes. How could I edit this handler so in the last emitter it would send my info from the last function.

I'm sorry if I'm being unclear here.

EDIT:

Solved by just using global variables.
So:

var event_type = null;
var myData = null;

Without editing the handler.
and then set the variables in the function and later you can use it in the event listener.
Not a very pro-efficient solution, but it worked for me.

Comment: Insead of editing, post an answer and accept it :) So other people know this question was already solved